# Bad colorscheme in Vim running on Putty+tmux

Tags: vim, putty, tmux

I'm trying to set up base16-tomorrow colorscheme in my Vim, which runs on top of tmux+Putty. I exausted nearly every link on Google to get it working, but nothing happens =S

This is how the colorscheme looks like now:
[image: Current l&f of base16-tomorrow on my PC]

How it was supposed to be:
[image]

The odd part is, no matter which base16 colorscheme I chose, it still looks the same.

Some informations about my shell:

```
$ echo $TERM        # on Putty
xterm-256color      # I configured putty to 256 colors and use this identifier
$ tmux
$ echo $TERM
screen-256color
```

Also, in Vim, `t_Co` variable is set with 256.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I guess you have chosen a 16 color theme, but can you mention in your question  what them you use ?

Comment: @XavierT., I mentioned the theme is base16-tomorrow, which is - at least, I guess - a 256 color theme.

Comment: Have you tried running tmux with `tmux -2` to force 256-color mode?

Answer (score 1):

Despite having this in my `.tmux.conf` file, it didn't help: `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`

However, this from @xthrd helped me:

> Have you tried running tmux with tmux -2 to force 256-color mode?

Answer (score 0):

I had a simular issue with displaying colorschemes in tmux.
Have you tried adding `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` to your .tmux.conf